# Popup Window in Kotlin dismiss when Application goes to background in Android 14

Tags: android, kotlin, popupwindow

The popup Window component get dismissed on android 14 devices automatically when application goes to background. This is working fine with older versions.

`binding = LytResetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) var popupWindow = PopupWindow(binding.root,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true) popupWindow.animationStyle = R.style.Animation popupWindow.showAtLocation(binding.root, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0)`

Any thought on this behavior will be appreciated.

This popup window should persist when application bring back to the foreground.